# What could be the keylength of a DES encryption?

Tags: encryption, des

What could be the keylength of the `DES` encryption if we have an output of `64` bytes?

Answer (score 4):

DES has a 56-bit key in 8-bytes. The length of the output depends on the length of the input, mode and padding, not the key.

Note: The LSb (least significant bit) of each key byte is reserved for parity, depending on the DES implementation parity may or not be checked.

See: [Data Encryption Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard).

Comment: Note that I have seen DES being used as synonym for 2 key or 3 key triple DES (which one is chosen during key configuration). That's of course not a correct use of the DES acronym (as there are other schemes based on DES), but I think it may be interesting for real world scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

`DES` is the *block* cipher with the

- *fixed* key length of `56` bits, and
- the *fixed* block size of `64` bits.

It is co called cryptographic *primitive* (something as building block for constructing real ciphers).

To cipher some message it must be first divided / padded to the *integer number of `64`-bits blocks*.

So the key length *must be* `56`-bits.

BTW., `DES` is now considered not be safe (mainly because of that short key length). Triple DES (`3DES`) is now (relatively simple) substitution for it (with the 3 times longer, i. e. `168`-bits key).

Comment: 1. CTR mode does not require padding. 2. There is also a lot of 2TDEA with a 112 bit key and that has been deprecated. 3. 3DES provides is only 112 bits of security due to a meet-in-the-middle attack. 4. Arguably a better upgrade for DES is AES.